# Edit i18 properties in runtime

Tags: java, jboss, properties, bundle, message

I have several message bundle files (eg. messages.properties, messages_de.properties, ...) and I need to edit those files dynamically in runtime (without restart app server).

For example, I would have html form which will load each file (select box), show properties to the user and user will have ability to change property's value.

I use java 1.6 with jboss 5.1.

Is there any service in jboss which I can use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java.util.Properties class. It provides methods to load, store the .properties file, to get and set the properties and more. For more information on how to use check [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) link from Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should better store the dynamic info in database, it will be easier to manage the data, when it becomes large.

Then you may provide a subclass of `java.util.ResourceBundle` to handle gettting the keys/values for your locale. That subclass should use database to retrieve the key-value pairs.